# External HDD not permitting writing ext4/ fat32 too small?

Tags: partition, external-hdd

I have formatted (using GParted) an external HDD for use as it was NTFS, but the writing permissions were denied, I then tried fat32 but the file size is too small, there is no exfat option, and I would like a password protect if possible when plugged in etc.

How can I get the drive to allow me to write and have a password if possible?  What is wrong in my ext4 process? Primary extension ext4 external hdd, all is seen, mounted and open-able but not writeable?

**I have just tried this using commands below, and it did not work either.**

```
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 625141759 625139712 298.1G  b W95 FAT32
```

```
$ sudo  wipefs -a /dev/sdb1
wipefs: error: /dev/sdb1: probing initialisation failed: Device or resource busy
david@david-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo  wipefs -a /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: 8 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000052 (vfat): 46 41 54 33 32 20 20 20
/dev/sdb1: 1 byte was erased at offset 0x00000000 (vfat): eb
/dev/sdb1: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001fe (vfat): 55 aa
david@david-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb1

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognised partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x5fd1458f.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): 

Using default response p.
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
First sector (2048-625139711, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-625139711, default 625139711): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 298.1 GiB.

Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Hex code (type L to list all codes): 7
Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'HPFS/NTFS/exFAT'.

**Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Failed to add partition 1 to system: Invalid argument**

The kernel still uses the old partitions. The new table will be used at the next reboot. 
Synching disks.
```

It says w is an invalid argument, so what do I do with that, is this option for exfat partitioning not available on linux mint? Or has the command changed?

**Now this issue is listed with the previously used command =**

```
$ sudo  wipefs -a /dev/sdb1
wipefs: /dev/sdb1: ignoring nested "dos" partition table on non-whole disk device
wipefs: Use the --force option to force erase.
```

What I type now, was from a website.

(exfat is apparently what is appropriate to use on multiple systems, so is preferred, ntfs is on gparted already, ext4 is last option preferred) unless other issue I don't know of with exfat? or is this not doable in linux?

Comment: i used gparted not commands

Comment: Are you intending to use the new partition for multiple operating systems (e.g. Linux and Windows)?

Comment: Please, clarify if you only ever want to use the drive under Linux, or for some reason, you need Windows/OSX access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unmount every partition and the disk as a whole:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb? /dev/sdb
```

---

Wipe the old partition scheme:

```
sudo wipefs --all --force /dev/sdb? /dev/sdb; sync; partprobe
```

Create partition:

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
```

`o` <kbd>Enter</kbd> for new empty GUID partition table (GPT)
`y` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm your decision
`n` <kbd>Enter</kbd> for new partition
<kbd>Enter</kbd> for default of first partition
<kbd>Enter</kbd> for default of the first sector
<kbd>Enter</kbd> for default of the last sector
<kbd>Enter</kbd> for Ext4 or `0700` for NTFS
`w` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write changes
`y` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm your decision

---

Create Ext4 filesystem:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -L Some_Label -m 0 -b 512 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0 /dev/sdb1
```

or

Create NTFS filesystem:

```
sudo mkfs.ntfs --no-indexing --verbose --with-uuid --label Some_Label --quick --sector-size 512 /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: I do not want it in ntfs as others have had issues with that.  That is why I am trying to set it to exfat.  Gparted allows ntfs already.

Comment: did not use, as I got lost in the last section. I used ntfs. Thanks though.

Comment: @dai Always welcome here ;)